# insert code listings in the scope of \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings, verbatim

In the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach\a in {x, y}{
\begin{verbatim}                                                                                                                              
  some code                                                                                                                                   
\end{verbatim}
}
\end{document}
```

the environment `verbatim` fails inside the scope of `\foreach`:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
```

Also the environment `lstlisting` fails:

```
Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing on input line 9.
```

How to insert code listings inside the scope of `\foreach`?

Comment: `verbatim` can not be an argument to any macro, including `\foreach`.  I have an additional question.  Your simplistic MWE doesn't explain how one set of `verbatim` code would be different than the next in the loop.  What did you have in mind there?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Inside the `\foreach` loop imagine some other things that depend on `\a`, deleted for simplicity. But initially I tried to use `lstlisting` depending on `\a` which seems tricky to accomplish.

Comment: The thing you want to achieve isn't possible in that way, as the argument of `\foreach` is already tokenized. `lstlisting` and other verbatim environments and macro depend on category code changes, which won't have any effect on already tokenized content. What you can do, is setup a box or something like that which contains your verbatim content and use that in your loop.

Comment: If you should insist on the verbatim approach then you will probably have to resort to reading an external file, as its contents will not be tokenized by the loop. But then it would be quite problematic to modify its contents depending on `\a`.

Comment: `verbatimbox` package allows you to stuff `verbatim` content into a box and recall it later, though I don't know how you would make it dependent on `\a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a solution by writing the verbatim material to an external file (with the tools of the package `verbatim`) and then inserting verbatim the file with `VerbatimInput` of `fancyvrb`. This last instruction can be put in a loop (here it's a loop of `expl3`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{baseline=t,commandchars=\\\{\}}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\iow_new:N \myverbatim_stream
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_now:Nn {NV}
\NewDocumentEnvironment {LoopVerbatim} {mmmm}
  {\iow_open:Nn \myverbatim_stream {myverbatim.tex}
   \tl_map_inline:nn {\ \\\{\}\$\&\#\^\_\%\~}
      {\char_set_catcode_other:N ##1}
   \char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M
   \cs_set:Npn \verbatim@processline
        {\iow_now:NV \myverbatim_stream \verbatim@line}
   \verbatim@start}
  {\iow_close:N \myverbatim_stream
   \int_step_variable:nnnNn {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4} 
        {\VerbatimInput{myverbatim.tex}}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother  

\begin{document}

\begin{LoopVerbatim}{1}{1}{10}{\i}
def f(x):
    return x ** (\i)
\end{LoopVerbatim}

\end{document}
```

Of course, you need escape characters in the verbatim. Here, `\`, `{` and `}` keep their TeX standard meaning (for Python, it's pretty good).